Is SO(2) with any entangling gate universal?
Let $E \in SU(2^k)$ be any entangling gate (for some $k \geq 2)$. Then my question is simply whether or not it is known that $SO(2) \cup \{ E \}$ is universal for $\mathsf{BQP}$?
Clearly it seems that this ought to be true, in light of the standard facts that any entangling gate with arbitrary single-qubit gates is universal, and that "real quantum computation" (computation with gates having only real entries) can also realize universality for $\mathsf{BQP}$.
I am just curious if anyone has seen the result made explicit that $SO(2) \cup \{ E \}$ is universal for any entangling gate $E$, or if this is something I'd have to prove myself?

It's not a result I've seen. Have you tried looking through the set of papers that cite the universality of Toffoli+H result? If it's been published, it would have to appear in such a list.

I have perused a few of them, as well as those that cite the result by Shi: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205115. I'll keep looking

Not sure if this works in general, but I believe the controlled-T gate works. We can apply a normal T-gate by controlling on an auxiliary qubit in the $|1\rangle$-state, and 4 controlled-T gates are equivalent to a CZ gate. I guess for this to work there should be some complex component in $E$ (so $E\not\in SO(2^k)$), I'm unsure of that though.

SO(2) or O(2)? Note that SO(2) does not even contain the Hadamard gate. (This seems especially unclear in the light about your comment on "real quantum computation", so it is not even obvious if E is the Toffoli.)

Ah fair point. Though in SO(2) we do have the "Hadamard-like" gate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. I think I'd like to restrict to SO(2) specifically.

@Mary_Smith I wouldn't consider this particular Hadamard-like (e.g. it rotates by $\pi/2$ while Hadamard rotates about $\pi$, and it rotates about a Pauli axis while Hadamard doesn't.) In particular, including a Hadamard would break the argument in the answer.

No. With the conventional notation of the Pauli basis, $SO(2) \cong U(1)$ rotations just constitute rotations around $Y$, i.e., these gates are parameterized by the set
$\{e^{i \theta Y} : \theta \in [0, 2\pi)\}$. For ease, let us redefine our basis so that we instead have rotations around the $Z$ axis. One can choose $E$ to be $CZ$, which is entangling. However, it commutes trivially with the above representation of $SO(2)$ rotations. Given that $\langle \{e^{i \theta Z} : \theta \in [0, 2\pi)\}, E \rangle$ is Abelian, it cannot be universal.

Instead of changing to the Z basis, one could also simply consider $e^{i\theta Y\otimes Y}$ as the entangling gate (for a non-nonsuitable $\theta$).

True, any entangling gate that respects Abelianity suffices in this argument. I chose CZ purely because it is a conventional gate.

The reason for suggesting this is mostly that it avoids having to change to the Z basis, which is potentially suspicious, or rather requires extra care. (After all, the basis change will get us out of SO(2), so one has to be careful that this does not break the argument; if you use $e^{i\theta Y\otimes Y}$, or e.g. instead transform CZ into the Y basis, you don't have this issue.

@NorbertSchuch The basis change is synonymous with saying that the copy of SO(2) in SU(2) described by $Y$ axis rotations is unitarily equivalent to the copy of SO(2) described by $Z$ axis rotations. We don't leave SO(2), just change representations.

This should probably be a different question, but should we restrict the notion of an entangling gate to be relative to the product states that are possible from the gate set? In that case this C-Z would only ever act as a global phase and not be entangling.

If $E$ is then defined to have nontrivial action on the achievable states, we probably also need to be careful then about specifying our allowed choices of initial states. Starting from only $|0\rangle$ states, $Z$ axis rotations + CZ is trivial. Our choice of initial states could allow for teleported gates, so the question probably needs to be carefully defined.
